# Cancel all modal transitions when presenting a new Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, modal-dialog, transition

I am looking for a way to cancel all ongoing modal transition.

I need to push a new view controller at any time of the life cycle of my app, therefore I can't rely on *viewDidAppear* delegate to start the presentation of this new view.

When one modal transition is already happening and I try to push (with animation) a new controller, I get the "Terminating app due to uncaught exception `NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempting to begin a modal transition from to while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed` crash.

My only alternatives are to push the new controller without animation, or find a way to cancel all pending modal transitions.

Any help?

Comment: I had a very similar situation arise - trying to display a "lock screen" whenever the user did a certain action, which could happen at any random time. I don't think there's any way to avoid this scenario - I can't find any way to either check for an app-wide transition in progress, or cancel any transition that's in progress, in order to avoid this exception from occurring. I think the only solution is to present the new view controller separately outside of the existing navigation stack - such as by creating a new `UIWindow` for it.

Comment: Did you find out the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have used the approach you suggested:

> "push the new controller without animation"

Pushing or presenting allow you to not use an animation, so I think it's good enough. As for what @Spynet suggested:

> better u just addSubView and do your animation u really don't want
>   modal or push like means...

You shouldn't mix `UIViewController's` `UIViews` in other(s) `UIViewController('s)`. The logic of rotation for instance is lost. Also the logic and behaviour of the `UIView` is also lost. If you want, you can easily create a `UIViewController` container and work with that. There is a [great video about it](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102) in the WWDC videos.

Comment: Well actually going with no modal transition between the view changes is a no Go. I need to find a way to cancel the modal transitions ongoing. Any hint on that ?